# Can a project have more than two environments in Composer?

Tags: php, automated-tests, composer-php

I have this `composer.json` file:

```
{
    "require": {
        "slim/slim": "2.4.*",
        "league/plates": "3.1.*",
        "michelf/php-markdown": "1.4.*",
        "zendframework/zendsearch": "dev-master"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "4.3.*",
        "maximebf/debugbar": "1.*",
        "openbuildings/phpunit-spiderling": "0.1.*",
        "jonnyw/php-phantomjs": "3.*"
    },
    ...
}
```

The `require` block is suitable for live, and the additional deps in `require-dev` are suitable for local development. However I find in my hosted continuous integration, I don't need three out of the four dev dependencies, either because they are not used or they are available already.

Can I set up another block (e.g. `require-test`) or can I create a new Composer file (e.g. `composer.test.json`) for this scenario? It's not a big deal to include things I don't need, but it feels a bit redundant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a lot of trouble for little gain. But you can if you can set environment variables and like to maintain a copy of your composer.json file.

```
By setting the COMPOSER env variable it is possible to set the filename of composer.json to something else.

For example:

    COMPOSER=composer-other.json php composer.phar install
```

[Link](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#composer)

Comment: Excellent, didn't find that! Doesn't seem like too much trouble here -- it'll speed up my builds, and I don't mind trying to lessen the load on free CI.